# Adding a contact summary tab

Tags: extension, developer

I am completely new to Civicrm and successfully created an extension that modify and existing page{Contact Page} but I am required to create a extension that shows a new CIVICRM Contact Tab that show list of Personal Campaign Pages created by a contact.I have not clue how to start creating this..Any tip on how to do this will be appreciated

Comment: You will need to explain a little more about what you want to achieve. Based on your question as it is I understand far too little about what you want to do to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tabset hook (detailed information can be found on the wiki here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_tabset) to add a contact tab.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where is needed to be called in my extension?

Comment: That is fairly basic, I would recommend you do a little background reading on extensions (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+an+Extension and https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension) and hooks in general (https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference)? Once you have done that it might be clearer and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CiviPoints extension that has an excellent example of how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Adding a tab to the contact summary page is a matter of implementing [hook_civicrm_tabset](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_tabset). You'll need to [add a page callback](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addabasicwebpage) to render the new tab content.